# "getpwnam() failed" in /bin/sh only when called from cron

Tags: shell, sh, cron

Here's the content of my crontab file:

```
SHELL=/bin/bash
PATH=/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
MAILTO="example@example.com"

*/5 * * * * sh /robot/1/master.sh >/dev/null 2>&1
*/5 * * * * sh /robot/2/master.sh >/dev/null 2>&1
*/5 * * * * sh /robot/3/master.sh
*/5 * * * * sh /robot/4/master.sh >/dev/null 2>&1
*/5 * * * * sh /robot/5/master.sh >/dev/null 2>&1
```

This is the error that keeps showing in `/var/log/cron` when it tries to run:

```
crond[669]: (sh) ERROR (getpwnam() failed)
```

If I run any of these files manually, they work without any issues.

What's wrong with the crontab file?

Comment: Aside: `sh` is not `bash` (even if it's a symlink to bash, it operates in compatibility mode, turning of numerous features). Don't tag your questions bash if you aren't actually *using* bash.

Comment: Are you trying to run the cron every half minute or every 5 minutes? The */5 means that it will run every minute with a step of 5.

Comment: anyhow, `getpwnam() failed` is pretty straightforward, in general. What's your system's directory service/store? If it's configured to talk to something that requires Kerberos authentication, for example, then your cron jobs may not have a valid ticket.

Comment: ...that is to say: The problem doesn't actually have to do with your crontab file, but it has to do with how your system's directory service -- which provides the information `getpwnam()` queries for -- is configured. That's going to mean digging around in your system's config a bit.

Comment: @DanielCortés */5 means it'll run every 5 minutes.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Looking into it right now, thanks!

Comment: Incidentally, I can't speak for whatever `/bin/sh` you happen to be using, but *bash* will recover gracefully from a `getpwnam` failure (err, sorta gracefully; it'll assume your user is called `I have no name!`, has a home directory of `/`, and has a default shell of `/bin/sh`). You might try setting `SHELL=bash` in your crontab, and using `bash` instead of `sh` explicitly.

Answer (score 112):

It surprises me that nobody has the correct answer to this. Today i faced exactly the same problem and google didn't help.

After 2 hours i found that when placing a file in /etc/cron.d the schedule line has to contain an extra option.....

I allways use this for my crontab -e

```
# Minute   Hour Day of Month     Month          Day of Week     Command    
# (0-59)  (0-23)   (1-31)  (1-12 or Jan-Dec)  (0-6 or Sun-Sat)  /my/fancy/script.sh
```

So it contains 6 items.

When placing this in a file inside /etc/cron.d the cron needs an extra option, being the user to run your fancy/script.

```
# Minute   Hour Day of Month     Month          Day of Week     Who   Command    
# (0-59)  (0-23)   (1-31)  (1-12 or Jan-Dec)  (0-6 or Sun-Sat)  root  /my/fancy/script.sh
```

This is documented in man crontab(5). For example https://linux.die.net/man/5/crontab . It says:

**Jobs in /etc/cron.d/**

The jobs in cron.d are system jobs, which are used usually for more than one user. That's the reason why is name of the user needed. MAILTO on the first line is optional.

Comment: Heh. Good point -- if you've got a system crontab with a missing field, we'd be looking for a user named `sh`, and that would certainly cause a `getpwnam()` failure.

Comment: not even the sys admins for my VPS have any clue what's causing it lol. btw, why have you used the path `/etc/cron.d/` and not `/etc/crontab`?

Comment: I use the directory `/etc/cron.d` because i can create one file with a descriptive name per task. Because i like it that way.... `/etc/crontab` is a file which is never modified by me.

Comment: @Anthony: Also this is the natural way to add crontab entries owned by a package. (Which is how I ran into this problem today.) This should be the accepted answer.

Comment: to make more clear: in cron.d you need to add the user name (root in this case) which runs the job

Comment: Thanks man, I did exactly the same error and you spare me hours of works !!!

Answer (score 4):

The sixth position is reserved for *username* running the job. You specified a user called `sh` which is most probably not present on the machine.

Answer (score 2):

simple answer
on your crontab you need to specify the USER to run the command

example to run as ROOT is:-

0,10,20,30,40,50 * * * * root /path_to_script/script_name

or to run as user FRED

0,10,20,30,40,50 * * * * fred /path_to_script/script_name

default with no USER specified is to run as user CRON and that user would not have permissions to execute the script

Answer (score 1):

We can create cron jobs for system as well for individuals. The crontab in `/etc/crontab` specifically used for system cronjobs. So you need to specify the cronjob command executed by whom. In the question the username not specified. Hence the `ERROR (getpwnam() failed)` occurs. You can create user specific cronjobs in `/var/spool/cron/username`

**NOTE:: Cron jobs are very useful but disastrous on failures!**

Comment: This solved my problem in CentOS 7 system

Answer (score 1):

Just if someone stumbles upon this:

I've had a similar problem. My Error Message was:

(root ) ERROR (getpwnam() failed)

the solution was to remove all spaces except one around the username root in the crontabs line.
I only had this issue on one machine, the same line with more whitespaces on other machines work fine so far...

Answer (score 0):

Nothing is wrong with the crontab file (so long as by "my" crontab, you mean that it's a user crontab rather than a system crontab; otherwise, [see other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42719311/14122)).

On the other hand, something is wrong with your system's directory service -- as configured, in Linux, with `nsswitch.conf`. Perhaps you're using a Kerberos-authenticated LDAP store, and your cron daemon doesn't have a Kerberos token to connect to it (or is sandboxed, as with SELinux, not to have network access); perhaps it's a file store that isn't readable by the user whose crontab is being run; perhaps some other odd and interesting thing is going on.

`getpwnam()` is a C library call that performs a lookup for the name of the currently-logged-in user. If your shell were *bash*, it would fall back to a name of `I have no name!` -- so this error means your `sh` implementation is something different. (If you want to run your scripts with bash, use `bash`, not `sh`).